# Wake on LAN doesn't work when power down from Windows

Tags: windows-10, bios, shutdown, wake-on-lan, hybrid-sleep

I'm attempting to use Wake on Lan turn on my Windows 10 computer from miles away, and I've gotten it to work when the computer is in sleep or hibernate mode, but not after it has been shut down. If I enter the computer's BIOS and turn it off from there (by pressing the physical power button), wake on lan DOES work, but if I shut down from within Windows, then wake on lan does not.

I assume that's because of this:

"In Windows 8, 8.1 and Windows 10, the default shutdown behavior puts the system into the hybrid shutdown (also known as Fast Startup) state (S4), and all devices are put into D3. In this scenario, WOL from S4 or S5 is unsupported."

from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2776718/wake-on-lan-wol-behavior-in-windows-8-windows-8-1-and-windows-10

**Is it possible to work around this somehow and get wake on lan to turn on the computer even after it has been shut down from within windows 10? If so, how?**

I have tried this with both fast startup enabled and disabled, but the results don't differ. The motherboard is an ASUS x99 deluxe with "Power On By PCI-E/PCI" enabled and "Wake On LAN" is enabled for all the ethernet ports.

Answer (score 3):

So, I found the resolution looking at the datasheet from intel I211

In Windows: Disable fast startup

in the device manager, in the driver properties and advanced tab, on top of

enable: Wake on Lan,

enable: Wake on Magic Packet,

enable: Wake on Pattern Match,

off: Energy Efficient Ethernet,

Forced: wake on link settings,

on: Wait on Link

Finally:
Enable PME shoule be enabled

OBS: some of those settings could have no effect on enabling WoL feature, but at this point I'm pretty drained from trying multiple things to troubleshoot this issue. So, if you want to troubleshoot to optimize that, let me know your settings later

Comment: For my Windows 11 system `Disable fast startup` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem on an ASUS X299 TUF and win 10. For me, the only work around I found was to use the second port (I219-V) and make sure "Energy efficient Ethernet" to Off in the adapter settings. Still, the other adapter (I211) with the same settings will only boot from a hard shutdown and never when turned off by windows. 
So you may want to try the other port if you have dual lan

Comment: `ASUS x99 Deluxe` is an entirely different motherboard than `ASUS x299 TUF`.  `I219-V` does not exist on the author's board.

Comment: I know it is different... I do have the exact same symptoms but on another intel X series motherboard made by asus. Both motherboard still share the I211, which is the one I do have a problem with.

Comment: I have an Aorus Pro with the same card (Intel I211) and can only WoL if I shutdown the computer by button, if I shutdown Windows or Ubuntu normally, WoL does not wake it up.

Comment: I'm having the same EXACT issue with my Asus z97 Deluxe.  It has worked perfectly for many years,  but after doing an in-place upgrade to reinstall Windows 11 cleanly, started the problem.

Comment: Did anyone every find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Hybrid Sleep is disabled. I disable Hibernate as well. Then, restart the computer to ensure the changes above have taken effect.  Now, shut down from Windows.  **Ensure the power light is OFF and not flashing.** Now try Wake on LAN.  It should work the same as if shut down from BIOS.

Comment: Hybrid sleep was originally enabled, but unfortunately disabling it, restarting, and trying again did not change anything; it still will not start up once it has been powered down from Windows.

Comment: I've seen this happen when "Deep Sleep" is enabled in the BIOS. Or maybe under the power management tab in the network adapter itself; there is also usually an option to "allow this device to wake the computer".

Comment: Check with normal (say just Suspend) Settings, when you turn off from Windows, does the power light go all the off?

Answer (score 0):

- Disable Hibernation, open PowerShell as Administrator and type `powercfg /hibernate off` and press enter.
- With some computers, you need to set the [sleep state](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/system-sleeping-states) in UEFI/BIOS to S1-S3 instead of S4. [Not always required](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/windows-10-wake-on-lan-not-working-from-shutdown/ba6ae540-b602-42f3-b5bb-afe95fe6661c), but sometimes needed.
- Disable energy/green options for NICs in UEFI/BIOS if available
- Enable WOL options for NICs in UEFI/BIOS if available
- Ensure you are using the correct MAC address for the WOL packet. This command in PowerShell lists your MAC addresses:
  `Get-CimInstance win32_networkadapterconfiguration | select description, macaddress`
- Go to all network adapters in Device Manager and disable anything "energy" or "power saving" or "green" related, and enable all "WOL" options.

[image: Energy Efficient Ethernet]
[image: Green Ethernet]
[image: Power Saving]
[image: WOL Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that worked for me on an Asus baord, after checking all the boxes which other guides suggest to no avail:

Instead of unchecking "Allow the computer to turn off this device", like many guides say, leave it checked, but also check "Allow this device to wake the computer" (as per picture).

[image]